# Why [project name] directory in [project name] directory?

Tags: flutter, dart

Developing with vscode, I noticed something strange.

If I developing `TestProject` project, there is `TestProject` folder in project file.
I mean a directory with the same name as the project exists in the project.

Inside that directory is very similar to the directory offensive of the parent project.
These directories inside it: `android` `assets` `ios` `lib` `public` `web`.

```
[Project name] directory
|- android
|- assets
|- ios
|-[Project name]
  |- android
  |- assets
  |- ios
  |- lib
  |- public
  |...
|- lib
|- public
|....
```

Sometimes I edit these directories by mistake. What is this? Is this directory essential for flutter projects? Even if I delete it, it is generated if I notice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the directory is essential for Flutter. In the future, when you create another project, don't touch the directory. You can add it of course, but don't change their default location. Pay attention.

For Example, if you want to add a directory for the image (generally calls assets), you can do it. But it will be in the directory [project-name].